# Runtime Error '1004'

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run this VBA code, but always get a Runtime Error '1004' Message

```
Dim clLookup As Range
Dim clDest As Range
Dim rws As Long

With wbk2.Sheets("SOA")
Set clDest = .Range("J2")
Set clLookup = .Range("G2")
End With

If clLookup.Offset(1, 0) <> vbNullString Then
rws = Range(clLookup, clLookup.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
Set clDest = clDest.Resize(rws, 1)
End If

clDest.Formula = "=TODAY()-" & clLookup.Address(False, False) & ""
clDest.Value = clDest.Value ' Convert to value
```

Comment: Is wbk2 set anywhere? Error 1004 could indicate that you try to use an object that hasn't been initialized

Comment: hi, yes it is and the sheet is usually open when the error occurs. Just for reference though: Dim wbk2 As Workbook 'NEW SHEET

Comment: The weird thing is that the same code works on other sheets; but its just this one that is not, driving me crazy for almost an hour now :)

Comment: Check if the sheet is protected

Comment: It's not, I My macro basically creates a new sheet and calls it "Wkb2" with Worksheet ("SOA"). Got you confused as well no? LOL Hate when stupid things take so much time to figure out !!

Comment: Yes, I'm quite confused. so at what line the code stops?

Comment: At this line "If clLookup.Offset(1, 0) <> vbNullString Then"

Comment: Although i do not get any "highlight" of the error, but when i check line by line, the one above is where it stops... No idea why. Is there a way i can upload my file? the code is quite long and would not want to past it here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64848/discussion-between-cynicalsection-and-user3800275).

Comment: I see you have got your answer. nice! next time you get an error like this one or another runtime error, click on debug, add to your question on which line the error occured, then we can help you much quicker ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is at this line: `rws = Range(clLookup, clLookup.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count`. 
**Range** object belongs to the execution sheet and not to the output sheet, SOA. 
This will work by changing the code to:

```
rws = wbk2.Sheets("SOA").Range(clLookup, clLookup.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
```