# Troubleshooting for Run-time error '1004': Application -defined or object-defined error

Tags: vba

I'm trying to create multiple sheets from a master spreadsheet and am up to the last few steps but unfortunately, I keep getting the above error? Can someone pleasee help me? Thank you

- The error line is showing the below as the problem:
  Sheet1.Range(Cells(10, 1), Cells(count_row, count_col)). _
  SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

Please see full code below:

```
Sub copy_data_2_new_sheets()

Dim count_col As Integer
Dim count_row As Integer
Dim dep As String
Dim check As Integer

check = 0

dep = Sheet1.Cells(2, 6).Text

On Eroor GoTo oops
Sheets.Add(AFTER:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = dep
check = 1


oops:
If check = 0 Then
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveSheet.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
End If

Sheets(dep).Cells.ClearContents
Sheet1.Activate
count_col = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A1", Range("A10").End(xlToRight)))
count_row_ = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A1", Range("A10").End(xlDown)))

ActiveSheet.Range("A10").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=dep

Sheet1.Range(Cells(10, 1), Cells(count_row, count_col)). _
SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
Sheets(reg).Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Sheet1.ShowAllData
Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = False


End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post an image of sheet1 with the headings?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Runtime Error '1004'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26904134/runtime-error-1004)

Comment: Welcome to SO. This issue has been covered many times, please see: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvba%5D+runtime+error+1004

Comment: Add `Sheet1` in front of the inner `Cells` calls.